# Android: how to disable screenshot programmatically and display its snackbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, screenshot, android-snackbar

I wanted to programmatically turnoff screenshot and display snackbar as "screenshot is been disabled with this tab".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: But it got just turning on with flags, need the snackbar or toast prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532502/detect-a-screenshot-android

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet in your activity to prevent screen capturing.

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

Comment: But for the snackbar?... That's important