# How to detect when a user screenshots? (React Native, IOS and Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to know when a user screenshots while being in the app for analytics. for both Android and IOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like there's not a direct way to do this, but somehow might be possible.
Take a look at these posts:
[iOS Detection of Screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)
[Detect a screenshot Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532502/detect-a-screenshot-android)

And for react native there's actually a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screenshot-detect) for that.