# Is there any way to take a screenshot of an entire grid view including the elements not on the screen?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-gridview

I have an android app with a grid view. The view typically has more elements than fit on the screen, and scrolling works normally to allow these to all be seen.

When I take a screenshot (with power and volume-down), the desired functionality is for the screenshot to be of the entire grid view. Android seems to know this as it gives me the option to "Capture more" which would normally allow you to select how long you want the image to be. When I press it however, it shows me the grid view with no option to extend the window as if I already have the entire view selected.

From what I understand, this may be because the individual views within the grid view are recycled, and so the entire view never exists at one time and as such can't have a screenshot taken of it. This could be fixed by implementing an [ExpandableHeightGridView](https://gist.github.com/jiahuang/2591977) although I would lose the benefits of recycling.

To implement this, I think I would still need to know when the screenshot was being taken which is a feature not coming until [Android 14](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/features/screenshot-detection) unless I wanted to [monitor the storage and edit the images post-save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532502/detect-a-screenshot-android) which isn't desirable.

**TLDR:**
Is there any way to take a screenshot of an entire grid view including the elements not on the screen and if I have to take the photo manually, is there a nice way to know when a screenshot has happened/pass my image off to the standard screenshot handler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a view to Bitmap without displaying it in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android)

Comment: Create the screenshot yourself, then you can generate the view all expanded, as it is not limited to the screen size when you draw direct to a bitmap (which can then be saved as jpg or png)

Comment: That could work, is there a nice way to know when the screenshot has been requested (power and volume) or would I need to add my own button? Also could I pass the screenshot I take with that method to allow the user to share and edit the photo as with a normal screenshot?

Comment: You could share via content provider to anything that handles pictures, but I think capturing the power key event is hard to do, so other key combinations or a button would be easier to trigger it.